# How to convert this function to a linear plot?

Tags: linear-model, curve-fitting

I have a series (data set) of values, $s$, which I expect to vary with $t$ as follows:

$s = p[1-2^{(-t/h)}]$, where $p$ and $h$ are unknown constants.

In order to estimate $p$ and $h$ from the data set, what function $f(s)$ can I plot against what other function $g(t)$ to get a straight line of the form:

$f(s) = m*g(t) + c$

Then how would I calculate $p$ and $h$ from the gradient $m$ and the intercept $c$?

Is this possible, or is there a better/easier way to estimate $p$ and $h$ from the data set of $s$ vs $t$?

Comment: I'd start with nonlinear regression directly applied to your first expression (e.g., nls in r). Or perhaps approximate the expression using a Taylor series.